# Getting StringIndexOutOfBoundsException even though my string is longer than the value it is giving

Tags: java

I keep getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 35018
 and telling me that 35054 characters is to large even though I just recently checked how many charecters there are and its around 7000 I was wondering if somebody could help me with this. This is the code in question.

```
         if (twojunglers[0].equals("hecarim")) {
            if (twojunglers[1].equals("leesin")) {
                String codeblock;
                String codeblock1;
                String codeblock2;
                while ((codeblock = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String makelinesintoone;
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((makelinesintoone = br.readLine()) != null){
                        builder.append(makelinesintoone);

                    }
                    int hi = builder.indexOf("Red\">");
                    if (hi >= 0) {
                        codeblock1 = codeblock.substring(0, hi);
                        int cutstring_ = codeblock1.indexOf("Champion\">");
                        if (cutstring_ >= 0) {
                            codeblock2 = codeblock1.substring(0, cutstring_);
                            System.out.println(codeblock2);
```

Comment: *"I keep getting StringoutofboundsException and telling me that 35054 characters is to large even though I just recently checked how many charecters there are and its around 7000"* That exception is telling you that index 35k is too large for a 7k characters long string and yet you wonder why that this is the case?

Comment: that is correct tom.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Best to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At least post the stacktrace from the exception and point out which line in the posted code it refers to.

Answer (score 0):

`StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an exception indicating that an index used on a `String` object is either negative or greater than the size of the `String`.

In your actual code, the problem is very probably caused by the `substring()` invocation below :

```
int hi = builder.indexOf("Red\">");
if (hi >= 0) {
    codeblock1 = codeblock.substring(0, hi);
```

You invoke the `indexOf()` on the `builder` variable that returns the `hi` int but then you invoke `substring(0, hi)` on the `codeblock` variable.
The problem is that `codeblock` and `builder` variables don't refer to the same `String` as you value them from two distinct read lines :

```
while ((codeblock = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

and :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while ((makelinesintoone = br.readLine()) != null){
   builder.append(makelinesintoone);
```

It makes no sense.

Comment: you are actually incorrect david they do not refer to the exact same string but they have the same contents in the string.

Comment: @Face123  Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very blunt as there is no full explanation or all of your code available. Maybe check what line is giving you the issue and update your question.

Although things to check to maybe save time.

Just make sure that you are assigning `strings` with `strings` and not `strings` with `chars` or `ints`, etc.

If you are getting a certain `char` outside of the bounds of the `string` using `charAt`.

Update your question with the full error please.